# error call to member function in pugixml?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

While using pugixml in visual c++ 2010, I recieve an error when I set value of int, string. I mean when I want to set int value, the function give me below error:

pugi::xml_node::set_value' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned int' to 'const pugi::char_t *'
or if I use string than:

pugi::xml_node::set_value' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'string' to 'const pugi::char_t *'

Can any body give some information how can I convert a string or int type value to const pugi::char_t*

Comment: If you have a `std::string s`, pass `s.c_str()`.

Comment: this work little bit, but now it gave me another error,                                  cannot convert from 'bool' to 'pugi::xml_node'

Comment: @khan, Your compiler will tell you exactly where in the code that error is. Look for the `bool` and compare what you're passing in with what the function expects.

Comment: it was same line, thanks removed it....